# Port SQL Server data to MySQL without Workbench

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mysql-workbench

When using `MySQL Workbench` to migrate data from `SQL Server` to `MySQL` I ran into a [bug that it won't escape apostrophes](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87459). In the interim I would like to still port that data over. Is there any simple way to do this?

I've exported my data into a file with `INSERT` statements but they don't match the syntax of `MySQL` (I'm new to `MySQL`) so I don't know if it would work, neither does the file contain semicolons at the end of each statement.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

So, far it looks like the easiest way to do it is to export the data into flat files and go through each table and make sure to also generate a `SSIS` file that you can use to automate future exports. Like so:

```
 DTExec /File MyExportedSissFileForOneTable.dtsx
```

And then use `PowerShell` or some other scripting language to do all the different files you need to update. Then import the files with `MySQL` - which I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: How big is the db you're trying to migrate?  If it's sufficiently small enough you may be able to achieve this quicker by *pushing* the data via SQL Sever over a [Linked Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/) connection.  You could also look into SSIS, but that'll probably require more work than *necessary* regarding a scenario where you're moving away from MSSQL.

Comment: I have about 41 tables with the biggest table having about 91k records (most are much smaller). So, a pretty small database. This is all on my local machine. After working on this project for a year my boss decided he wanted MySQL instead of SQL Server :-(

Comment: I'm actually porting to MySQL not PostgreSQL

Comment: Gah!  What's wrong with my eyes!  Regardless, check Github to see if you can find some existing solutions that may make your life easier.  Apparently I have db dyslexia...

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect it is probably nicer to just roll my own converter since `MySQL` uses `snake case` instead of `title case` like `SQL Server`.

So, what I'm going to do is use a `PowerShell` script like so:

```
$tables = "FirstTable", "SecondTable"
function script {
    param(
        [System.String] $table
    )
    "set nocount on; select * from dbo."+$table
}

$tables |
% {
   $path = "C:\Data\"+$_+".txt"
   $script = script $_
   sqlcmd -S MyServer -d MyDatabase -W -h -1 -E -Q $script -s `"`t`" -o $path
}
```

This will export all the data from my `SQL Server` database and put them in files and then I will import those files into `MySQL`. Which I haven't quite figured out yet. I let the `MySQL Workbench` do the initial `CREATE TABLE` statements and used `Vim` to make everything snake case.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server, `bcp out`.

On MySQL, `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

For moving data, have you looked at `bcp`?  It's the "Bulk Copy Program" for SQL Server.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility. Set the row and column terminators to something not in your data ~EOC~ ~EOR~, etc.

You can use "`LOAD DATA INFILE`" on MySQL to bulk load flat files.  Again, set your row and column terminators.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

I would use plain batch files for this, since I always had problems calling certain executables with PowerShell, usually when passing in arguments.